# Bidirectional OneToMany relationship with composite entity key cause null identifier

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am struggling with mapping a one-to-many bidirectional relationship with composite primary keys based on entites. I have created some classes that represents what I want to do. They are just made so it is easier to explain, but I think they communicate what I am trying to do well.

I have left out implementing some interfaces/methods, but I can ensure you that it works when I don't add the set of tournaments to the Player/Game entity. So something is wrong with my mapping.

When I try to find an entity (pretty much do anything) Hibernate 4.x cause a null identifier error saying nothing more about the error.

What would be the correct way to map this when I have a composite primary key on the "one" and I want bidirectional navigation?

```
@Entity
@IdClass(TournamentPk.class)
public class Tournament {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("player_id")
    private Player player;  
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("game_id")
    private Game game;
    private int score;

    // Getters and Setters
    // Hashcode and Equals
}

// Primary key class.
public class TournamentPk {

    private Player player;
    private Game game;

    // Getters and Setters
    // Hashcode and Equals
}


@Entity
public class Player {

    // ID
    // Other fields

    @OneToMany(fetchType = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "player")
    private Set<Tournament> tournaments;

    // Getters and Setters
    // Hashcode and Equals
}

@Entity 
public class Game {

    // ID
    // Other fields

    @OneToMany(fetchType = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "game")
    private Set<Tournament> tournaments;

    // Getters and Setters
    // Hashcode and Equals
}
```

Comment: Try to use `@EmbeddedId` instead of `@IdClass`

Comment: Could you provide the exact exception message? The error occurs when you try to find an entity of what type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you annotated with `@Id` fields of not-allowed types (e.g of type `Player` and `Game`). See the documentation of the [@Id](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Id.html) annotation for details

*Note for completeness: [some references](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id#Application_Set_Primary_Key_) allow to have another Entity class annotated with @Id.*

1. In your place I would have an independent `@Id private Long id;` field in your `Tournament` entity + an `@Unique` constraint on the Game+Player combination with a standard mapping.
2. If you really want to stick with `@IdClass`, you might try adding two allowed fields in your tournament class (I have found a similar mapping [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/SetIdClassforCompoundKey.htm) (search for @IdClass)).

---

```
  @Entity
  @IdClass(TournamentPk.class)
  public class Tournament {

    @Id
    @Column(name="player_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long playerId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("player_id")//consider adding cascade=PERSIST
    private Player player;  

    @Id
    @Column(name="game_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long gameId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("game_id")//consider adding cascade=PERSIST
    private Game game;
    private int score;

    // Getters and Setters
    // Hashcode and Equals
}

  public class TournamentPk {

    private Long playerId;
    private Long gameId;

    // Getters and Setters
    // Hashcode and Equals
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I realized that using entity as PK didn't work so I changed to embeddedid and used the same mapping as you have written. But when I did I got duplicate column mapping (column and joincolumn have same names) so I had to add insertable=false and updateable=false. However, when I save I don't get a record in the database..

Comment: You mean you tried solution 2 (`@IdClass` and not `@EmbeddedId`). I have added `updatable=false,insertable=false` to my code, thanks. Are you sure you don't get an exception when you try to save a record (it is hard do believe that)? If you get one, please post the stacktrace. What do you think of solution 1? Did you try/think to use `@EmbeddedId` instead of `@IdClass`?

Comment: I have changed to approach 1, I think I am one step closer by using simple fields in the embeddable ID and another set of manytoone. I think that is right. I must look at it tomorrow. I will post what I find.